# How to send a data larger than 8 bit to I/O ports

Tags: assembly, 8051

I am new to assembly language programming. I am trying to make four common annode 7 segment led display which can count up to 9999 using at89c52 MC. But i cant send data above 255(FFH) to the I/O ports.
so is there anyway i can send data above 255 or 8 bit to the i/o port and to led display

```
ORG 000H
MOV DPTR,#LUT              
MOV P1,#00000000B          
MOV P0,#00000000B          
MAIN: MOV R6,#14D
  SETB P3.5
  MOV TMOD,#01100001B  
  MOV TL1,#00000000B   
  MOV TH1,#00000000B   
  SETB TR1             
BACK: MOV TH0,#00000000B   
  MOV TL0,#00000000B   
  SETB TR0             
HERE: JNB TF0,HERE         
  CLR TR0              
  CLR TF0              
  DJNZ R6,BACK
  CLR TR1              
  CLR TF0              
  CLR TF1              
  ACALL DLOOP          
  SJMP MAIN            
DLOOP: MOV R5,#100D
BACK1: MOV A,TL1           
   MOV B,#100D
   DIV AB              
   SETB P1.0
   ACALL DISPLAY       
   MOV P0,A            
   ACALL DELAY         
   ACALL DELAY
   MOV A,B
   MOV B,#10D
   DIV AB              
   CLR P1.0
   SETB P1.1
   ACALL DISPLAY       
   MOV P0,A
   ACALL DELAY
   ACALL DELAY
   MOV A,B             
   CLR P1.1
   SETB P1.2
   ACALL DISPLAY       
   MOV P0,A
   ACALL DELAY
   ACALL DELAY
   CLR P1.2
   DJNZ R5,BACK1       
   RET

DELAY: MOV R7,#250D        
 DEL1: DJNZ R7,DEL1
   RET

DISPLAY: MOVC A,@A+DPTR    
     CPL A             
     RET
LUT: DB 3FH                
 DB 06H
 DB 5BH
 DB 4FH
 DB 66H
 DB 6DH
 DB 7DH
 DB 07H
 DB 7FH
 DB 6FH
END
```

is there any solution??

Comment: "i cant send data above 255(FFH) to the I/O ports", you could not send data above to **single** port. But you could send 4 values for 4 different ports

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. -- Yes, multiple ports, or you can use time-multiplex. Do some research, please.

Comment: Please show us the circuit how you connected the display to the µC.

Comment: @thebusybee: From the code it is quite obvious: The anode of each 7-segment display is connected to P1.0, P1.1 and P1.2; if he wants to count to 9999, a fourth 7-segment display is required; the anode can be connected to P1.3 for example. The 7 cathodes of the LEDs are connected to the inverted pins P0.0-P0.6 (maybe 7 NOT gates (NPN transistors) are used as amplifier). Each of these pins is connected to 4 cathodes (the same LED in all 4 segments).

Comment: I do not look into code if the OP tells us "I can't...". ;-) So I tried to trigger a bit more effort to help us help.

Answer (score 1):

> send data ... to the i/o port and to led display

It seems that you haven't fully understood how your circuit works:

The pins P1.0 to P1.2 specify which 7-segment digit is switched on and the pins P0.0 to P0.6 specify which digit is shown on the corresponding segments.

Example:

If port P0 has the value 6, the digit "1" is shown. If P1.0 and P1.2 are on and P1.1 is off, the first and the last segment are active and the middle segment is inactive (so `1_1` is shown). If P1.0 is off and P1.1 and P1.2 are on (and P0 still has the value 6), `_11` is shown.

What your program is doing is: It writes some value (for example 6 to produce the digit "1") to P0 and switches P1.0 on and P1.1 and P1.2 off. So the first digit is "1" and the other two digits are off.

Then it switches off the first digit and switches on the second digit. So actually, only one digit is active ("visible") at the same time! However, this happens so fast that your eye does not notice it and you think that all three digits are permanently visible.

> count up to 9999

You will need a 4th 7-segment digit for a 4-digit decimal number!

> data above 255 or 8 bit

There are two possibilities:

1. **The upper 8 bits of the counter are stored in the TH1 register.**

You might perform a 16-bit division (divide a 16-bit value by 100). However, performing a 16-bit division on an 8-bit CPU is by far not as simple as a `DIV` instruction!

You have to perform shifting operations in a loop...

You can take the quotient of the division by 100 and divide it by 10 using `DIV`; the quotient and the remainder are the first and the second digit. (The reminder of the division by 100 is divided by 10 to get the third and the last digit.)

2. **Use two counters that both count to 100...**

Instead of directly passing the value of TL1 to the display, you define two counter variables (for example H and L):

To add a value X to your counter, you add X to the variable L.

If L reaches the value 100, you increment H and subtract 100 from L.

Now the value of your counter can be expressed as 100*H+L: H contains the first two and L contains the last two decimal digits of a 4-digit decimal number.

If you define two additional variables N and O, you can do that the following way:

```
Initialize:
L = 0
H = 0
O = TL1 (= 0)

Before sending data to the display do:
N = TL1
L = L + N - O
O = N
divide L by 100
H = H + quotient
L = reminder
(and optionally):
   divide H by 100
   H = remainder

Now:
L contains a number in the range 0-99 reflecting the low 2 digits
H contains a number in the range 0-99 reflecting the high 2 digits
```